# How to close/remove volume/file created by bdemount (Bitlocker)

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, windows, encryption

After I use `bdemount` to decrypt a Bitlocker encrypted volume on my Linux system, how do I close the volume?

First I decrypt the volume like this

> sudo bdemount -p MYPASSWORD /dev/sda1 /mnt/bdem1

This will create a file `/mnt/bdem1/bde1` (930 GB =~ size of disk /dev/sda1).

Then I mount the file like this

> sudo mount -t ntfs /mnt/bdem1/bde1 /mnt/sda1_ntfs

I now have the NTFS volume mounted under `/mnt/sda1_ntfs` and can access it.

Now for the reverse operation. I can unmount the NTFS volume

> sudo unmount /mnt/sda1_ntfs1

But the "decrypted" volume under `/mnt/bdem1/bde1` still exists. How do I "close" this one without damaging anything? To my surprise the file `/mnt/bdem1/bde1` even persists after I log out and then log in again.
I was expecting something like a `bdeumount` command, but there is no such thing and the man pages don't mention this "reverse operation" at all.

My system uses Ubuntu 20.04 with bdemount 20190102.

Answer (score 0):

libbde/bdemount uses [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) to create the volume so you can unmount/close it using `fusermount -u /mnt/bdem1`

Comment: When I try this, all I get is "fusermount: failed to unmount /mnt/sdc2_bde: Device or resource busy" each time every time.

Comment: You must first unmount the NTFS filesystem on the BDE device.

This is what I do to mount the device: `sudo bdemount /dev/sdX /mnt/bde -p <password>` and `sudo mount -o loop,ro /mnt/bde/bde1 /mnt/ntfs` and to unmount it: `sudo umount /mnt/ntfs` and `sudo fusermount -u /mnt/bde`.